# Let f be an r-cycle in $S_n$. Given any $h \in S_n$, show that $hfh^{-1} = (h(x_1), h(x_2), \dots, h(x_r))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

The problem: let $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_r)$ be an r-cycle in $S_n$. Show that for every $h \in S_n$, $h \circ (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r) \circ h^{-1} = (h(x_1), h(x_2), \ldots, h(x_r))$

Answer (score 1):

For $i \notin \{h(x_1), \dots, h(x_r)\}$ you have 
$$h \circ (x_1 \  \dots \ x_r) \circ h^{-1}(i)= h \circ h^{-1}(i)=i$$

And for $i =h(x_j) \in \{h(x_1), \dots, h(x_r)\}$ you have 
$$h \circ (x_1 \  \dots \ x_r) \circ h^{-1}(i)= h \circ (x_1 \  \dots \ x_r)(x_j)=h (x_{j+1})$$

Comment: How did you eliminate $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r)$ in the first part? It seems to me that in order to eliminate it, one has to know that $h^{-1}(i) \not\in \{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_r\}$. How did you derive that from $i \not\in \{h(x_1), \ldots, h(x_r)\}$?

Comment: If $h^{-1}(i)=x_j$ then $(h \circ h^{-1})(i) =i=h(x_j)$